# O3DE and physics

Tags: game-engine

On the O3DE website here: https://docs.o3de.org/docs/user-guide/interactivity/physics/

It is said that:

> Open 3D Engine (O3DE) provides several Gems that you can use to simulate physics. With the PhysX Gem you can create PhysX colliders for collision detection and rigid body simulation, triggers for script events, and force regions to localize forces such as wind. The NVIDIA Cloth Gem provides tools to simulate cloth and create cloth properties and constraints. The PhysX Debug Gem provides debugging and visualization tools for PhysX colliders and simulation.
>
> NVIDIA PhysX  Learn about the PhysX tools you can use to create colliders and triggers, as well as components and functionality that simulate physics.
>
> NVIDIA Cloth  Learn about the cloth mesh modifier that generates cloth meshes, how to set cloth properties and constraints, as well as the components and functionality that simulate cloth.
>
> Debugging PhysX   The PhysX Debug Gem includes several console variables (CVARS) and an Immediate Mode GUI (IMGUI) overlay that you can use to visualize and debug PhysX simulations.

Moreover, here: https://www.docs.o3de.org/docs/welcome-guide/supported-platforms/

It is said that:

> Target Platform Platform-specific Documentation

> Microsoft Windows,
> Linux,
> Android,
> macOS experimental,
> iOS experimental

And in this regard, my question is: how can O3DE support Android, MacOs and iOS - if the physics simulation component only depends on Nvidia video cards?

Comment: O3DE relies on PhysX SDK 4 or newer, which supports android, as well as other platforms https://developer.nvidia.com/physx-sdk-for-games Also PhysX executes a lot of stuff on CPU without any GPU backing.